# UnparseableJsonResponse: API Version 1

Tags: actions-on-google

My first app for Google Home has just been released, but it's in the "unhealthy" status.

Looking at the logs, I see that the response received is :

```
Received response from agent with body: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Mar 2018 16:36:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 174
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Google-Actions-API-Version: 2
expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache: MISS
{"expectUserResponse":false,"finalResponse":{"richResponse":{"items":[{"simpleResponse":{"ssml":"<speak>This is AppBundle\\ActionsOnGoogle\\DictionaryEndpoint</speak>","displayText":"This is AppBundle\\ActionsOnGoogle\\DictionaryEndpoint"}}]}}}.
```

and yet I have "UnparseableJsonResponse: API Version 1: Failed to parse JSON response string with error"

I can't understand what's wrong with health probe :

- My Google Home work fine (conversations are okay)
- It works fine in the simulator too
- API version in response is "2" not "1"
- JSon response is valide

Anyone can help ?

Thanks

Frederic

Comment: I forgot "fulfillmentApiVersion: 2" in action.json, but after "gactions update", it's still a version 1 that health probe is waiting for.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, did you have to send a response back to the probe in V1 format?

Comment: I updated my action file with "fulfillmentApiVersion: 2" and submit for review. Now, it's okay.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'd forgotten I had asked this.That's exactly what I did as well.